# Regarding constant * opt approximation in agnostic learning

Tags: complexity-theory, machine-learning, computation-models, learning-theory

In standard agnostic learning, we assume that there is a concept class $H\subseteq \{h:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$. Given samples from a distribution $D:\{0,1\}^n\times \{0,1\}\rightarrow [0,1]$, the goal is to output the best $h\in H$ for which $err_D(h)\leq C\cdot opt+\varepsilon$, where $opt= \min_{h\in H}err_D(h)$ and $err_D(h)=\Pr_{(x,b)\sim D}[h(x)\neq b]$ and $C=1$.

Now, are there any natural examples where outputting a $h$ satisfying the above is simpler when $C$ is a constant $>1$? In some sense, what is the relationship between agnostic learning when $C=1$ or $C>1$ is some arbitrary constant? Suppose an algorithm satisfies $C=10$, does it imply we can produce another algorithm (with a polynomial overhead) for which $C=1$?

Comment: As I recall, in agnostic learning, the $h$ that achieves the optimal sample complexity is the empirical risk minimizer (i.e. you should find $h \in H$ which disagrees with the minimum number of samples). This is some minimization problem on your samples, which by itself can be NP-hard. It also can be NP-hard to approximate; some problems can only be approximated up to some factor $\alpha$. For such cases, setting $C = \alpha$ would simplify the problem.